# Is it possible to debug runtime generated groovy code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, jvm, remote-debugging

I'm working on a project where we need to compile groovy classes at runtime and then instantiate objects from these classes and execute methods on it. The source for these classes exists as a string only in live environments.
These classes can contain pretty complex code, so there is a good chance of bugs hiding in there.

The problem with our approach is, that when we notice missbehavior in these classes, we can't use a comfortable method of debugging.
We can of course write and execute tests against these classes, but often times you just want to know what's going on step-by-step.

**So my question is: Is there is a way to debug runtime generated groovy/Java classes?**

The steps we currently take to track down bugs:

1) Write tests to reproduce the behavior

2) Read through the code. (obviously has a super bad success rate in complex classes)

3) Do instrumentation. We call a static "_break" method which we have written in a utils class (so no runtime generated stuff). In that _break method we can add a breakpoint. So this is almost as if we were debugging the runtime generated classes directly. The Problem with that approach is, that you have to recompile and add a new version of the groovy classes to the testsystem everytime you want to add/remove a _break call.

If you're wondering how we can even write tests for these classes, here is how:

For unit tests we copy the code from the strings into regular groovy classes. These are used for development and unit testing, because it gives us code completion and a fast way to at least execute the classes against simple tests.
We can debug the code on unit test level. The problem here is, that the data setup is too complex to reproduce certain combinations in unit tests.

For integration tests, we do the whole compilation, adding, executing process, just like it would happen in the live system.

We use Intellij 2017 as IDE and I currently have no idea if or how we could "connect" the bytecode to either the strings which is was generated from, or the copied groovy classes we use for unit testing.
Any other tool that would allow us to debug would be fine as well.